# Vim syntax file to be stricter about HTML syntax

Tags: html, vim, syntax-highlighting, strict

I just got bit by a bug that was

```
 <link rel=stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="all">
```

rather than

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="all">
```

It seems like vim's syntax highlighting for html doesn't differentiate between the two.  Is there a stricter syntax file I can get from somewhere?

(and for the haters: [vim questions belong on stackoverflow, not superuser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a stop-gap measure, I put a copy of `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/html.vim` in `~/.vim/syntax/html.vim` and modified it:

```
38c38
< syn match   htmlValue    contained "=[\t ]*[^'" \t>][^ \t>]*"hs=s+1   contains=javaScriptExpression,@htmlPreproc
---
> syn match   htmlValue    contained /=[\t ]*\%('\%(\\.\|[^\\']\)*'\|"\%(\\.\|[^\\"]\)*\|[^'" \t>]*\)/hs=s+1   contains=htmlString,javaScriptExpression,@htmlPreproc
40c40
< syn region  htmlTag                start=+<[^/]+   end=+>+ contains=htmlTagN,htmlString,htmlArg,htmlValue,htmlTagError,htmlEvent,htmlCssDefinition,@htmlPreproc,@htmlArgCluster
---
> syn region  htmlTag                start=+<[^/]+   end=+>+ contains=htmlTagN,htmlArg,htmlValue,htmlTagError,htmlEvent,htmlCssDefinition,@htmlPreproc,@htmlArgCluster
43a44
> syn match   htmlTagError contained /['"].*/
168c169
<   syn region  htmlScriptTag     contained start=+<script+ end=+>+       contains=htmlTagN,htmlString,htmlArg,htmlValue,htmlTagError,htmlEvent
---
>   syn region  htmlScriptTag     contained start=+<script+ end=+>+       contains=htmlTagN,htmlArg,htmlValue,htmlTagError,htmlEvent
```

This just catches this particular error (mismatched quotes), so I'm still very interested in a better syntax file for strict html.